# What is required to activate cgroups in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, lxc, cgroup

I have a Debian squeeze kernel (linux-image-2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64) which according to the Doku should support cgroups. When I look into the kernel configuration, it does (or is some other kernel configuration required?)

```
# zgrep -i cgroup /boot/config-2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64
# CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED is not set
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
# CONFIG_CGROUP_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_BLK_CGROUP is not set
CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP=y
```

Also, according to http://wiki.debian.org/LXC, a kernel parameter cgroup_enable=memory might be necessary. I started the kernel with it:

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64 root=UUID=6332fe39-7eaa-4519-b6c1-e05808284586 ro cgroup_enable=memory quiet console=ttyS0,57600n8
```

However, the system still has no cgroup support! The cgroup file system cannot be mounted as the file system type is not even known to the system:

```
# mount -t cgroup none /cgroup
mount: unknown filesystem type 'cgroup'
```

and:

```
# grep -i cgroup /proc/filesystems
#
```

So there is either a bug or I miss something. Can anyone tell me what?
Is there a kernel parameter missing?
A kernel configuration?

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass an -o to tell it what to mount.

```
mount -t cgroup -o memory cgroup_memory /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
```

And that's assuming that /sys/fs/cgroup is mounted at all.

```
mount -t tmpfs cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Ubuntu has a package named **cgroup-lite** which can do all this at boot. It doesn't appear to be in Debian so I'm not sure what the equivalent might be.

Note: I cannot add comments so I have to simply answer your question this way. For example: I wanted to ask if you had checked your kernel logs (**dmesg | grep cgroup**).

Answer (score 3):

You should mount like that[[1]](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch-Using_Control_Groups.html):

```
$ mount -t cgroup -o <cgroup_subsystem> name /cgroup/name
```

cgroup_subsystem can be[[2]](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html): {blkio, cpu, cpuacct, cpuset, devices, freezer, memory, net_cls, net_prio, ns}

You can also mount cgroups with the help of fstab (static information about the filesystems). Add this line to /etc/fstab to mount it at system boot with default cgroup subsystems.

```
$ cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup  cgroup  defaults  0   0
```

Comment: Hi, What `name` would you put as the argument before the last one? I see in the other answer it could be `cgroup_memory`. Is that what you expect?

Comment: Ok, I found that the answer is in the kernel doc. The name is just something easy to remember and it is also put into `/proc/mounts`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your distribution and kernel version. You can use following script from Docker to test `cgroups` and container related features:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/master/contrib/check-config.sh -O cgroups_check && chmod +x cgroups_check
./cgroups_check
```